# importing from MongoDB to google sheets, numbers output is {"$numberInt":"3204"}, how do I clean this for only the numbers to show?

Tags: mongodb, google-sheets

I am importing data from MongoDB to Google Sheets via web hook. My issue is that the output of numbers is like that {"$numberInt":"3204"}, how do I set it so only the number show?
this is the script:

```
function importMongoDBData() {
 var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("mongoDB")
 var getData = UrlFetchApp.fetch('URL').getContentText()
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(getData)
Logger.log(getData)
for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(jsonObj[i]._id.$oid)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 2).setValue(jsonObj[i].status)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 3).setValue(jsonObj[i].amount)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(jsonObj[i].frequency)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 5).setValue(jsonObj[i].Payments)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 6).setValue(jsonObj[i].maxAmount)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 7).setValue(jsonObj[i].Requested)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 8).setValue(jsonObj[i].Offer)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 9).setValue(jsonObj[i].term)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 10).setValue(jsonObj[i].user)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 11).setValue(jsonObj[i].details)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 12).setValue(jsonObj[i].vendor)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 13).setValue(jsonObj[i].createdAt)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 14).setValue(jsonObj[i].updatedAt)
  sh1.getRange(i+2, 15).setValue(jsonObj[i].boundaryAmount)
}

}
```

Comment: Could you show some of the data that comes in the `getData` variable ?

Comment: How does the `jsonObj` variable look like?

Comment: Logging output too large. Truncating output. [{"_id":{"$oid":"1234"},"status":"Approved","amount":{"$numberInt":"41324126"},"frequency":"monthly","Payments":{"$numberDouble":"134134"},"maxAmount":{"$numberInt":"1234234"},"Requested":{"$numberInt":"12341234"},"Offer":{"$numberInt":"1234134"},"term":{"$numberInt":"12"},

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that each value that comes from your database has this format: `{"$numberInt":"41324126"}`, in order to process this value you will have to make use of the `slice` method:

```js
// value here is equal to the jsonObj[i].amount

let value = '{"$numberInt":"41324126"}';
let result = value.slice(value.indexOf(':') + 2, value.lastIndexOf('"'));
console.log(result);
```

The `slice` will return the part of string between these two indexes:

- `indexOf(':') + 2` - which corresponds to the index of `':' + 2` which is in fact the start of the number;
- `lastIndexOf('"')` - which corresponds to the index of the last occurrence of `"` which is the end of the number.

Therefore, depending on your needs, you will have to process every value before setting it on the spreadsheet.

#### Reference

- [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice);
- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf);
- [Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf).